# Python logging module does not work under Phusion Passenger

Tags: python, flask, passenger

I've tried to use the logging Python module in my local machine and it worked fine.

But when the same (Flask) code is deployed to Dreamhost shared hosting, where it runs under Passenger, the logging simply does not work. The log file is not created and nothing is logged.
The rest of the code runs fine, just logging is ignored.

Why?

Thank you,
Márcio

Comment: hey! does your python process have enough permissions to create a log file? I had similar trouble which resolved by creation of this file and `chmod` it enough for my py process user.

Comment: @juggernaut Following you suggestion I did `touch log.txt` and `chmod 777 log.txt` and accessed the site, but the log  file does not receive any log and keeps zero bytes in size.